# Find element in selenium based on attribute/value in div class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using selenium in Python to try and scrape multiple pages. ID's and XPATH's keep changing per page, so I figured I'd best access them through their attribute-value combinations (see below).

I'm trying to access the text in the following element:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly1YU.png
which belongs to the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/strep.png

As I said, the ID's keep changing, so I wanted to access the element by data-fragment-name="articleDetail",  or data-testid = "article-body". Can somebody help me how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

obj = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-fragment-name='articleDetail']")
obj2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='article-body']")
```

where of course `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` or something like that and you already moved to the desired page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following CSS_SELECTOR

```py
div[data-fragment-name='articleDetail'] div[data-testid='article-body']
```

Or XPath

```py
//div[@data-fragment-name='articleDetail']//div[@data-testid='article-body']
```

The Selenium command can look like:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-fragment-name='articleDetail'] div[data-testid='article-body']")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-fragment-name='articleDetail']//div[@data-testid='article-body']")
```